# Good practice with local list of parameters

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of parameters that will be used in different functions. I don't want to give them a global value so I thought on creating a list of parameters that I can call locally.

As an example, I would like to not have to type the `{a = 1, b = 0.5, c = 0.75}` part of the Block each time, just call my list of parameters:

```
f[x_, a_, b_, c_] := a*x + b + b*c;
g[y_, a_, b_, c_] := b*y + c + a*c;
h[z_, a_, b_, c_] := c*z + a + b*c;
Block[{a = 1, b = 0.5, c = 0.75}, Solve[f[x, a, b, c] == 0, x]]
Block[{a = 1, b = 0.5, c = 0.75}, Solve[g[y, a, b, c] == 0, y]]
Block[{a = 1, b = 0.5, c = 0.75}, Solve[h[z, a, b, c] == 0, z]]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't, just put values in `f[x, a, b, c]` -> `f[x,1,.5,.75]`?

Comment: I would still have to type these values each time I call each function. I would like to have a list of parameters so when I call each function they are evaluated at exactly the same values of parameters.

Comment: Something like `f[x_, a_:1, b_:0.5, c_:0.75] := (* stuff *)` then?

Comment: Something like:`Block[{the list for {a,b,c}}, Solve[f[x, a, b, c] == 0, x]]
Block[{{the list for {a,b,c}}, Solve[g[y, a, b, c] == 0, y]]
Block[{{the list for {a,b,c}}, Solve[h[z, a, b, c] == 0, z]]`. Hopefully it is clearer :)

Comment: I agree that on my example above it is not local, but on my problem it would be local.

Comment: What about `Solve[f[x, ##] == 0, x]& @@ {1, .5, .75}`?

Comment: It would work if I could call the right hand side `{1, .5, .75}` as a list. For example: `list->{1,.5,.75} Solve[f[x, ##] == 0, x]& @@ list`

Comment: @LauraK doesn't it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't @Kuba.

Comment: `f[x_, a_, b_, c_] := a*x + b + b*c; list = {1, .5, .75}; Solve[f[x, ##] == 0, x] & @@ list`

Comment: Ahh, I replaced the `##` with `{a,b,c}`. Now it completely works. Thank you very very much. You were great!

Comment: in this case the following may be useful: `pars= Sequence[1,.5,.75]` then you could just use:  `Solve[f[x,pars]==0,x]`

Comment: also possible: `list={a->1,b->0.5,c->0.75};f[x,a,b,c]/.list`

Comment: @sebhofer, that is also a good idea. Thank you.

Comment: @sebhofer, this still doesn't solve my multiple typing problem. But thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since no one seems to dare an answer, let me give you one. At some point, you have to insert the values you want, but there are several shortcuts to make life easier especially if you want to insert the same at several occasions.

If you have like in your case a block of expressions, then one easy solution is to use `With` (which inserts values rather than creating local variables, but `Block` would work too) and surround all expressions where you want your paramters replaced:

```
f[x_, a_, b_, c_] := a*x + b + b*c;
g[y_, a_, b_, c_] := b*y + c + a*c;
h[z_, a_, b_, c_] := c*z + a + b*c;

With[{a = 1, b = 0.5, c = 0.75},
 {Solve[f[x, a, b, c] == 0, x],
  Solve[g[y, a, b, c] == 0, y],
  Solve[h[z, a, b, c] == 0, z]
  }
 ]
```

Comment: Ah, of course. That is exactly what I needed. Thank you very very much, @halirutan!